# Extract hours and minutes DateTime from time in database

Tags: php

My problem is, I have a Time value like '17:00' in my Database.

Sometimes i should extract from this Time '17:00' only hours like '2' or only minutes '03' and sometimes all togheter '05:03'.

This values come from Database to.

I need output like this

Time  '17:00'

hours and minutes from database Hour = '2' and Minutes = '30'

**Output: 14:30**

How can i do it?

```
$timeFromDatabase = '17:00';

$dbTime = new DateTime("$timeFromDatabase");
```

Comment: Maybe bulletpoint or list the different types of out put you want to get. I'm a bit confused as to the exact output you want. looks like there are about 3-4 different outputs you could potentially want.

Comment: In addition to what @JasonJoslin suggested, could you use the same time in all your examples. It feels like you're switching times on us so that makes everything more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$d  = '17:00';
echo date("H:i",strtotime($d."-2 hour -10 minute"));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But is it possible to do it with DateTime()?

Comment: i don't use this but i can try